# How to define for the textBox, that there are no spaces allowed (only letters, numbers, or signs other than space/tab/enter) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I mean the user has to enter his name into textBox, but he only has to enter his name (for example). Just one word together. No spaces at all.
If user enters for example : "John", thats ok, if user enters: "John A" it should be incorrect input.

How to define that?

Comment: Have you tried or search anything for that?

Comment: I would check for whitespace, something like `function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery then you can try something like this.

```
$('#<textboxid>').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        return false;
    }
});
```